# how to display image and left side and text right side in html

Tags: html, css

Hi in the below code i want to display images left side and text should be right side.but now it's displaying down of the image .and as well as 3 images in a single line same like image with text.

```css
.specilites{
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding-top:7px;
    color:#008080;
    font-size:30px;
}
.specilites img{

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    -moz-border-radius:50px;
    border-radius:50px;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    display:inline-block;
     border: 1px solid #008080;
}
.specilites h1{
    width: 1050px;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        padding-top:7px;
        color:#008080;
        font-size:30px;
    }
    .specilites td{
        font-size:15px;
         display:block;

    }
```

```html
<div class="specilites">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/>
       Accident & Emergency Care</td>
         <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
         <td> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/><td>
        </tr>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/>
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
      </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want 3 images in a single line and image left with text right to that. DEMO [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/wfmsjvsb/)

```
.specilites{
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding-top:7px;
    color:#008080;
    font-size:30px;
}
.specilites img{

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    -moz-border-radius:50px;
    border-radius:50px;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    display:inline-block;
     border: 1px solid #008080;
}
.specilites h1{
    width: 1050px;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        padding-top:7px;
        color:#008080;
        font-size:30px;
    }
    .specilites td{
        font-size:15px;
     /*    display:block;*/

    }
<div class="specilites">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
            <td>Accident & Emergency Care</td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi text displaying above like my output

Comment: @ hsp care: what do you want exactly? how your output should like?

Comment: @ hsp care: you can shift now the text's <td> where you want to display your text means after whatever image that you need.